# Storing Historical Data using History table in ASP.Net Core

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, audit

I have an entity in my database linked up with multiple entities and I need to store historical data for the changes (insert ,updates and delete) in the base entity as well as children entities.

Now the approach we are thinking of adopting is to keep every data in the corresponding history entity. The base table looks like this :

```
public partial class Con 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Document> Document { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ConLine> ConLine { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Leg> Leg { get; set; }
}
```

And the historical table looks like this, **I am not sure about how to design the history table to hold linked tables data**:

```
public partial class ConHistory 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ConId { get; set; }
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Document> Document { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ConLine> ConLine { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Leg> Leg { get; set; }
}
```

How do I approach this problem and What are the best industry practices? My main concern is when a child's data is being changed how do I log in to parent history table and the corresponding child history table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple time-series data, keeping a separate table with a copy of the modifiable fields is a perfectly valid approach. Unfortunately, in your case you would also need to make a copy of each of the linked tables as well, so that you can maintain consistent foreign keys - e.g. `DocumentHistory`, `ConLineHistory`, `LegHistory`. It's a lot of repetitive code. And then you have to consider, *what happens to all the historical records when the schema changes?*

Personally, I would store this information as json, in a text column. All the fields that you search on should be in sql, so that you can index it, but the rest can be serialized to a json string:

```
public partial class ConHistory 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ConId { get; set; }
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    public Guid ModifiedByUser { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    // Serialize the rest of the `ConHistory` fields to a json object, and store them here
    public string Json { get; set; }
}
```

Sql also has the `JSON_VALUE` function, and there are some examples of using this in Entity Framework, if you do need to get values out of the json string for querying.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I need to query the historical data for auditing. Each time I run a query do I have to convert json data to actual object? Or is there any other approach available?

Comment: one more thing all these data: con, conline, document, leg will be posted in the same transaction. How would you tackle that scenario if we keep separate history tables?

Comment: You can create a custom [ValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) to handle converting from json to a strongly typed object. As per your second comment, I'm not sure I understand what the question is but I'll try to address it.

Comment: If you do decide to keep them all in separate history tables, you can either: simply insert the parent object, and EF will traverse the navigation properties and add the child objects to the appropriate tables as well. Or: you can keep the logic in the database, in a SQL insert trigger. I'm not sure what volume you're talking about, but EntityFramework is a bit slow when it comes to inserting complex heirarchies. It inserts the individual entities one by one, and waits for the id to come back. For small throughput, this is fine, for large throughput it is not.